# How to add a plugin to the requirejs r.js optimizer, that only runs during build?

Tags: javascript, build, module, requirejs, optimization

I'm trying to write a custom script/plugin to be included in the requireJS r.js optimizer (for fingerprinting static files and one for bundling JSON resources).

What I have not figured out is how to trigger my custom-optimizer during the build process. I can write the scripts allright, but how would I trigger a `bundle-build.js` module during optimization.

Thanks for hints!

**EDIT:**
I know I can use 'onBuildRead/Write', but this is not the place to add a optimizer plugin. Something like [require-css](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css) is closer, but a file prefix, which triggers the plugin, which has a `pluginBuilder` specified to use during build. Not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizer should pickup all files that are specified as dependencies. If you need to include something extra then you can add extra logic using onBuildRead or onBuildWrite callback, where you can add/remove extra stuff:

```
({
    name: 'main',
    baseUrl: '../',
    // optimize: 'none',
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    exclude: ['jquery'],
    mainConfigFile: '../main.js',
    out: '../main.min.js',
    // A function that if defined will be called for every file read in the
    // build that is done to trace JS dependencies.
    // Remove references to console.log(...)
    onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
        return contents;
        // return contents.replace(/console.log(.*);/g, '');
    },
    onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
        // Add extra stufff;
        return contents;
    }
})
```

Comment: I have been looking at these, too, as well as using a [prefix!/pluginbuilder](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html#apipluginbuilder) plugin as well as the [internal API](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API:-onResourceLoad) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/wOSAa25d6xY) page. I'm still playing around with `onBuildRead/Write` but I was hoping to find some hook/etc which allows to tap into the optimizer during processing, so I could just try to write an "optimizer plugin" without having to add all the logic `onBuildRead/write`. Still. Thanks!

Comment: still have not found a nice hook, so I will check for now, because the info is correct. Thanks for helping out!